# Apache Wicket : How to add PropertyModel to checkbox object

Tags: java, apache, wicket, wicket-1.5

code is as follows

> < input type="checkbox" wicket:id="dsChk"/>

java

> CheckBox dsChk = new CheckBox("dsChk");

i don't want to use following constructor

> CheckBox dsChk = new CheckBox("dsChk", new PropertyModel(metaCommentTechSpeedBean, "dsChk"));

instead I want to add my Model via method

typically something like

> dsChk .add[.....< add modedl>.................]

please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

`dsChk.setDefaultModel(new PropertyModel(metaCommentTechSpeedBean, "dsChk"));`

Or take a look a [CompoundPropertyModel](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Working+with+Wicket+models#WorkingwithWicketmodels-CompoundPropertyModels)

Then you get something like this

```
CompoundPropertyModel<MetaCommentTechSpeedBean> props = 
    new CompoundPropertyModel<MetaCommentTechSpeedBean>(metaCommentTechSpeedBean);
Form<MetaCommentTechSpeedBean> form = new Form<MetaCommentTechSpeedBean>("wicketid", props);
CheckBox dsChk = new CheckBox("dsChk");
form.add(dsChk);
add(form);
```

The CompoundPropertyModel will set the correct PropertyModel based on the wicketid you give to the CheckBox object. In the forms `onSubMit()` call you can do `getModelObject()` to get the MetaCommentTechSpeedBean object.